# Deriving the COM of a hemispherical shell

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Problem:

> Derive the COM of a hollow hemisphere of mass $M$ and radius $R$ using Iterated Integrals in Cylindrical Coordinates.

I have no idea as to how  to go about this problem using Cylindrical Coordinates. I just derived the COM of a solid hemisphere and have shown my approach below.

$$Z_{CM}=\dfrac{\int zdm}{\int  dm}$$
$$dm=\rho rdrd\theta dz$$ since $|J|=r$.

Hence,

$$\large{Z_{CM}=\dfrac{\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^R\int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-z^2}}\rho rz\text{    }drdzd\theta}{M}}$$

On computing this Integral, I get $Z_{CM}=\dfrac{3R}{8}$. However, I have no clue as to how to extend this to a hollow hemisphere. I would be truly grateful for any help with this problem. Many thanks in anticipation!

Comment: Are you sure that there is no inner and outer radii for your hollow sphere ??

Comment: Yes. It's actually supposed to be a hemispherical shell.

Answer (score 1):

We should assume that this shell $S$ is infinitely thin, but has mass $1$ per unit of area.

An "infinitesimal latitude zone" of width $ds$ at geographical latitude $\theta\in\bigl[0,{\pi\over2}\bigr]$ has area
$$d\omega=2\pi R \cos\theta\>ds=2\pi R^2 \cos\theta\>d\theta$$
and height 
$$z=R\sin\theta$$ over ground. The $z$-coordinate of the center of mass of $S$ is therefore given by
$$z_c={\int_S z\>d\omega\over\int_S d\omega}={\pi R^3\int_0^{\pi/2}2\cos\theta\sin\theta\>d\theta \over2\pi R^2}={R\over2}\ .$$
If the hemispherical shell $H$ has a positive thickness, i.e., an inner radius $a$ and an outer radius $b$, then one has to compute volume integrals. The coordinates to choose are then **spherical**, and not cylindrical, coordinates. The volume element is given by
$${\rm d}V=r^2\cos\theta\>{\rm d}(r,\phi,\theta)\ .$$
Here, as before,  $\theta=0$ at the equator, and $r^2\cos\theta$ is the Jacobian. Since we still have $z=r\sin\theta$ we now obtain
$$z_c={\int_H z\>{\rm d}V\over \int_H {\rm d}V}\ .\tag{1}$$
By elementary geometry one has
$$ \int_H {\rm d}V={2\pi\over3}(b^3-a^3)\ ,$$
and the numerator in $(1)$ can be "separated" into
$$\int_H z\>{\rm d}V=2\pi \int_a^b r^3\>dr\cdot \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\theta\cos\theta\>d\theta$$
(note that the integration with respect to $\phi$ is for free). I may leave the last two integrals to you.

Comment: Thanks you Sir. Sir, could you please explain your terminology a bit? I'm quite unfamiliar with it, using instead the term 'infinitesimally thin ring'  as an  example. I wasn't able to understand what an 'infinitesimal lampshade'  is.